# DNS resolution works for nslookup but fails in browser while using openconnect

Tags: vpn, dns, macos

Trying to use `openconnect` to connect to Cisco Anyconnect VPN.

I just did `brew install openconnect` and use it from cmd line like this:

> sudo openconnect --authgroup=VPN-SSL-GROUP -u FIRST_LAST@domain.com vpn.domain.com

Then I try to access **resource.domain.com** name from private network and get:

- in Chrome: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`
- in Network Utility -> Lookup: resource.domain.com -> The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)

BUT it gets resolved when I use `nslookup` from command line:

```
nslookup resource.domain.com
Server:         10.66.0.1
Address:        10.66.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    resource.domain.com
Address: 10.66.110.24
```

I decided to check the content of `/ect/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 10.66.0.1
nameserver 10.66.0.2
nameserver 192.168.100.1 # (this is the DNS address of my home router)
```

and see that required DNS addresses used by `nslookup` are in place. (If I use resolved address in browser, I successfully access private resource, so routing works fine)

I googled a bit and [learned](http://diaryproducts.net/about/operating_systems/mac_os_x/overriding_dhcp_or_vpn_assigned_dns_servers_in_mac_os_x_leopard) that DNS resolution works not the way I can expect from Linux. There is a `scutil` utility which can help to manage actual DNS settings.

Here is a list of my DNS settings which I can see in `scutil`:

```
> list .*DNS
  subKey [0] = Setup:/Network/Service/47AA11B0-4713-41EF-B532-FC580ACD3E75/DNS
  subKey [1] = State:/Network/Global/DNS
  subKey [2] = State:/Network/MulticastDNS
  subKey [3] = State:/Network/PrivateDNS
  subKey [4] = State:/Network/Service/47AA11B0-4713-41EF-B532-FC580ACD3E75/DNS
  subKey [5] = State:/Network/Service/utun1/DNS # (this one appears when I am connected using openconnect)
```

The content of `State:/Network/Global/DNS` and `State:/Network/Service/47AA11B0-4713-41EF-B532-FC580ACD3E75/DNS` keys match and is equal to:

```
<dictionary> {
  ServerAddresses : <array> {
    0 : 10.66.0.1
    1 : 10.66.0.2
    2 : 192.168.100.1
  }
}
```

The content of `State:/Network/Service/utun1/DNS` (which only exists after openconnect established connection) is:

```
<dictionary> {
  DomainName : location.domain.com
  SearchDomains : <array> {
    0 : location.domain.com
  }
  ServerAddresses : <array> {
    0 : 10.66.0.1
    1 : 10.66.0.2
  }
  SupplementalMatchDomains : <array> {
    0 : location.domain.com
  }
}
```

The other dns-related keys are empty.

I also tried to go Preferences -> Network -> my Wy-Fi connection -> Advanced and set DNS addresses manually. Still does not work.

And I also learned about [vpnc-script](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/vpnc-script.html) for openconnect. I found it already existed on my machine and tried to specify it explicitly:
`--script /usr/local/etc/vpnc-script` but it did not help to resolve private domains.

From what I see in `scutil` it seems to be properly configured, but for some reasons DNS resolution does not work. Any ideas why? What else I can check and try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to this answer: https://superuser.com/a/86245/356729

The command

> networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 10.66.0.1, 10.66.0.2

solved the problem. When I disconnect, I also have to manually restore settings using:

> networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 192.168.100.1